`react-native-render-html` library causes the text to cutoff on samsung s23 device (may be on a few other android devices as well)
I am using a library called react-native-render-html to render HTML content on mobile. It works fine on iOS and android devices except a few like Samsung Galaxy S23 where the text gets cuts off at the end. I've tried the same on other android devices and it works fine where all the text is rendered on to the screen.
I am not sure if this might be due to screen resolution. There's no limit on the text length and I am able to render larger text than this.
Code

const myStyles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({

  ...
    messageText: {
    fontFamily: myFont,
    color: grey800,

    // NOTE: If I bump this to fontSize to 14.5 or more, then the text shows up without cutting it off which is strange. For some text it doesn't work

    fontSize: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 14.5 : 14,
    lineHeight: 20,
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
  ...

})

['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'li'].forEach(tag => {
  tagsStyles[tag] = myStyles.text as MixedStyleDeclaration;
});


.....

  {text && (
    <HTML
     debug
     tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
     source={{
        html: text,
     }}
     contentWidth={containerWidth}
    />
  )}


When I increase font size it works, but I can't rely on that alone. For some text, making the font 14.001 works but 14 cuts off the text. For some other text, 14.5 works but not 14.001.
Because of this random behaviour on some Samsung devices like Galaxy S23, I am not sure what fontSize would be ideal. I checked this library's documentation, but couldn't find an answer. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.
Note: The text "toilet" gets cuts off as shown in the screenshot.


After a bit of a research, I found the answer for this, so just posting it here so it might help if someone runs into the same.
The problem was with the font-size. If we hardcode the fontSize then the same applies to all the devices. Some device might need more granular number due to it's screen resolution/pixel ratio. So when defining the fontSize, it would be better to scale them as per the screen size and pixel ratio (pixel ratio) seems optional as the behaviour doesn't change on adding it; but good to have it.
Code Addition
  import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

  // Base dimensions (these are the dimensions you design for, e.g., 375x812 for iPhone X)

  const BASE_WIDTH = 375;
  const BASE_HEIGHT = 812;

  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

  // Scale the font size

  const scale = (size: number) => {
    const scaleFactor = Math.min(width / BASE_WIDTH, height / BASE_HEIGHT);

    // return Math.round(size * scaleFactor); // if not considering pixelRatio

    const newSize = size * scaleFactor;
    return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize));
  };

const myStyles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({

  ...
    messageText: {
    ...

    fontSize: scale(14)
    
    ...
  },
  ...

})


Why do we need to add a reference device here

Scaling Consistency: The idea is to have a consistent scaling factor across different devices. By comparing the current device's screen dimensions (width and height) with the BASE_WIDTH and BASE_HEIGHT, you create a scaling factor that adjusts UI elements proportionally, maintaining a similar look and feel regardless of the device's screen size.

Responsive Design: Different devices have different screen resolutions and aspect ratios. By using a baseline, you ensure that elements like font sizes, paddings, and margins scale proportionally. This helps in creating a responsive design that looks good on both smaller and larger screens.


